# s3 copy object copy one folders contents to another

Tags: amazon-s3, copy

hey guys im trying to copy the contents of one s3 folder to another s3 folder using nodejs and aws sdk. But im really confused as to how to do this. 
whenever I do a basic copy it says access denied. But the larger issue is I have folder that contains many sub folders I want to copy all of its contents and place it under a new key. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you show us some code? What specific error are you experiencing? If it is Access Denied, then make sure you have read permissions on the source folder and write permissions on the destination folder. Also, what do you mean by "place it under a new key"? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function will do it perfectly

```
async function copyDirectoryS3(bucketName, oldPrefix, oldS3Id, newS3Id) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    // "templates/"+oldS3Id+"/"
    Prefix: oldPrefix
  };
  const listObjectsResult = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
  listObjectsResult.Contents.forEach(async ({ Key }) => {
    let currentKey = bucketName + "/" + Key;
    let oldId = new RegExp(oldS3Id, "g");
    let finalKey = currentKey.replace(oldId, newS3Id);
    finalKey = finalKey.replace(bucketName + "/", "");

    let copyParmas = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      CopySource: currentKey,
      Key: finalKey
    };
    await s3.copyObject(copyParmas).promise();
  });
  return newS3Id;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.